# How to decipher this number hiding algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hello so i am doing sms marketing for my product and i am scraping a phonenumber website having link https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Readymade-Garment-Retailers/nct-10401947 , this website hide numbers of contact by alloting them class names like `mobilesv icon-jie` , the letters written after `-` are important as they represent numbers from 0 to 9 , earlier these were static but look like now they are dynamic and changing on every time I refresh so earlier what i used to do was :

```
storeDetails = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('store-details')
contactList = storeDetails[i].find_elements_by_class_name('mobilesv')
         
        mynumbers = []

        for j in range(len(contactList)):
             
            myString = contactList[j].get_attribute('class').split("-")[1]
            print(myString)
            mynumbers.append(strings_to_num(myString))
```

Main logic function(`strings_to_num` which mapped the class to numbers) was:

```
def strings_to_num(argument):
     
    switcher = {
        'dc': '+',
        'fe': '(',
        'hg': ')',
        'ba': '-',
        'vuk': '0',
        'ikj': '1',
        'nmg': '2',
        'hgd': '3',
        'oqp': '4',
        'fde': '5',
        'baa': '6',
        'dcb': '7',
        'trs': '8',
        'rqi': '9'
    }
    return switcher.get(argument, "#")
```

But this is no longer working now , can someone help me to sort this out as it is wasting my time , thank you

Comment: i dont know why someone wants more focus , when i have provided every details , if you want more details i am willing to share

Comment: The close reason here is slightly misleading. There are not really multiple questions here. We used to have a "too broad" reason which included "lacks effort or demonstration of any research" but the correct close reason now would really be "needs details or clarity". Anyway, please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask;](/help/how-to-ask) perhaps you can still edit this into a form which is acceptable on Stack Overflow. The _real_ question here seems to be how to reverse engineer a piece of JavaScript which you are not showing us and which could change every time we visit it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your string_to_num logic on this code, and it worked fine. please try to edit it according to your app logic

```
my_string = "fde-dc-rqi"
arguments = [string for string in my_string.split("-")]
my_num = ""
for arg in arguments:
    my_num += strings_to_num(arg)
print(my_num)
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts but this is not working as u can see the class name is dynamic

Comment: would you please provide **driver** variable info, or at least an example value for it?